# Defining a bunch of functions with eval (PHP)

Tags: php, function, eval, heredoc

Is this anywhere near something acceptable? I need a function for each HTML tag, and they need to be defined for later use in a Heredoc string. This is my code so far.

```
<?php
$tags = array (h1, h2, h3, b, i);

foreach ($tags as $key => $value)
{
    eval ('function '.$value.' ($str) { return "<'.$value.'>$str</'.$value.'>"; }');
}
```

This basically takes care of the Heredoc problem concerning functions within heredoc. A quick example:

```
<<<example
<h1>This is ordinary HTML</h1>
{$h1('This is HTML via. PHP')}
example;
```

I did all the code over by heart, so please don't be suprised if they contain any errors. I haven't executed the eval-function yet, but it looks alright. Anyway, my question would be: Is this okay, or is it better to go do it the hard-way:

```
function h1 ($str) { return ...; }
function h2 ($str) { return ...; }
function h3 ($str) { return ...; }
function b ($str) { return ...; }
function i ($str) { return ...; }
```

And so on ..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [create_function](http://php.net/create_function) provided by PHP but...Since the code is simple why not just use one function to rule them all?

```
function createTag($tag, $text) {
     return "<{$tag}>{$text}</{$tag}>";
}
```

Should do what you are after.

As an after thought, you might want to check out the [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/dom) as that would probably be the route to go, but will take some time to learn and get used to using it.

Comment: Honestly, I was Google'ing so hard for that baby there! Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you could live with a more elaborate:

```
 <h1>This is ordinary HTML</h1>     
 {$h->h1("This is HTML via PHP.")}
```

Then it would suffice to define a single:

```
class html {
    function __call($name, $args) {
        return "<$name>$args[0]</$name>";
    }
}
$h = new html();
```

Would be faster than multiple eval roundtrips to define functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use an ugly hack anyway, I'd much rather do:

```
function create_html($tag, $val) {
    return "<{$tag}>{$val}</{$tag}>";
}

$html = 'create_html';

<<<example
<h1>Test</h1>
{$html('h2','Another test')}
example;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on PHP 5.3, you could use closures. *Far* superior to `create_function`. Avoid `eval()`.