# PHP dynamically define bunch of functions

Tags: php, function, eval, alias

Is there a way to define few similar php function dynamically in a manner like

```
define('MAX_LOG_LEVEL', 10);

_log_level( $string, $level = 0 ) {
   global $loglevel;
   if( $level >= $loglevel ) {
     file_put_contents(...);
   }
}

for($level = 0; $level < MAX_LOG_LEVEL; $level++) {
   function _log$level( $string ) {
      _log_level( $string, $level );
   }
}
```

that's because i have to create my own log routines and to quickly add an log information on demand.

I know the php built in [create_function](https://www.php.net/create_function) that do not really do what i exactly want because will be necessary to import the reference variable in the function/method that use that

I can't also use the `eval()` function as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423593/defining-a-bunch-of-functions-with-eval-php) since it is disabled on the final application hosting.

Comment: Explain pls, what you want to achieve? From your example - functions _log0, _log1,... _log9, which calls _log_level($s, 0..9)?

Comment: Why are you choosing to do it this way instead of just one function that takes the level + string as an argument?

Comment: Aliases, such as Python's `Logger().debug()`, `.info()`, `.warn()`, `.error()`, and `.critical()`.

Comment: Why not use more descriptive terms like debug, info, warning, error, fatal, etc.?

Comment: @andy: simply i think is more elegant have a `_log0( something )` instead of `_log(0, something)`

Comment: @user3025491, sorry but in common practice _log0().._log9() is far less elegant than _log(0..9,). It's has a real sense if you have meaningful names like `.debug(), .info(), .warn(), .error(), and .critical()` as @tyteen4a03 wrote.

Comment: Well it's not because you end up clogging the function spaces and it's nowhere near as flexible as the latter. If anything it's 10x worse.

Comment: @andy I had not thought about that!

Comment: see also the answers to "How can I create a function dynamically?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549496/how-can-i-create-a-function-dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to assign an [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to a variable and call it like so:

```
foreach (range(1, 9) as $i)
{

  ${'_log' . $i} = function($string) use ($i)
  {
    echo 'Log ' . $i . ': ' . $string;
  };

}

// Outputs Log 9: Test
$_log9('Test');
```

Another possibility is to use [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) (although you can't use it on your current application it might be possible in future environments):

```
foreach (range(1, 9) as $i)
{

  eval('

    function _log' . $i . '($string)
    {
      echo \'Log ' . $i . ': \' . $string;
    }

  ');

}

// Outputs Log 9: Test
_log9('Test');
```

If using this latter method take note of the warning in the manual:

> **Caution** The **eval()** language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. *Its use thus is
> discouraged*. If you have carefully verified that there is no other
> option than to use this construct, pay special attention *not to pass
> any user provided data* into it without properly validating it
> beforehand.

However, as others have mentioned in the comments, it is perhaps best to not define a unique function for each log-level: instead define a single function with the log-level as a parameter:

```
function _log($i, $string)
{
  echo 'Log ' . $i . ': ' . $string;
}

// Outputs Log 9: Test
_log(9, 'Test');
```

A further extension to this is to define the log levels to make it clearer to both yourself and to future programmers what exactly is being logged:

```
define('_LOG_CRITICAL_ERROR', 9);

function _log($i, $string)
{
  echo 'Log ' . $i . ': ' . $string;
}

// Outputs Log 9: Test
_log(_LOG_CRITICAL_ERROR, 'Test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible; you can do this:

```
$function = '_log' . $level;
$function($string);
```

This is known as a [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Comment: this is not I want to achieve: I want to call exactely _log0, _log1, ... Not to have a pointer to them

Comment: My code example _does_ call the function with the specified log level in its name. If you want to call many of them, wrap the above in a loop.